# Laravel 5.6 api response

Tags: php, laravel, api, controller

My `API` returns several account `objects`, I would like to list it in my `view`, but I do not know how.
Can someone help me?

**Method**

```
   public function get(){
    $client = new  client([
        'headers' => ['content-type' => 'application/json' , 'Accept' => 'application/json'],
    ]);
  $response = $client->request('GET','https://lusp.com/api/login');

  $data = $response->getBody();
  $data = json_decode($data);

  dd($data);


}
```

**Response**

```
    {#491 ▼
      +"accounts": array:2[▼
        0 => {#465 ▼
          +"id": 7
          +"email": "Ivan@mail.com"
          +"password": "4154512"
        }
        1 => {#466 ▼
          +"id": 1
          +"email": "lucas@mail.com.br.br.br"
          +"password": "lucas123"
        }
]
}
```

sf

Comment: Use $data = $response->toArray(); I think this will work

Comment: `Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()` , i need import? ?

Answer (score 1):

`dd` is not ideal to return,
try to return it like this

```
$data = collect(son_decode($data));
return response()->json($data);
```

if you're returning it into a view, do it like the following

```
$data = collect(json_decode($data));
return View("yourviewname",$data);
```

and in yourviewname.blade.php

```
@foreach($account as $line)
 <span> {{$line->email}} </span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it is not working because I think I return object of account, I'm not returning an array  **error** `array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
`

Comment: `Undefined variable: accounts(View: C:\www\API_ESTUDOS\Api_app_teste\resources\views\index\index.blade.php)`

Comment: if before you return it to the view you do `dd($data)` what does it return?

Comment: `$data = collect(json_decode($data));` , `dd($data)`

Comment: `Collection {#492 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼ 
    "account" => array:26 [▼
      0 => {#465 ▼
        +"id": 7
        +"email": "Ivan@mail.com"
        +"password": "4154512"
      }
      1 => {#466 ▼
        +"id": 1
        +"email": "lucas@mail.com.br.br.br"
        +"password": "lucas123"
      } ]]}`

Comment: Edited my answer, i belive it was a variable name problem